# Django request.data is giving wrong JSON

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I send a request to the server with {"name" : "Robert"} but the request.data looks different. This works fine in runserver. But when used uwsgi in docker it gives something like,

{
"_content_type": "application/json",
"_content": "{"name":"robert"}"
}

Comment: Community can help you if you can show how you send the request to the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.